# how can I make an alias pointing to a link in zsh-shell (on mac)

Tags: macos, zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to make this in my .zshrc-file:

```
alias fer='/Documents/hej'
```

But I'm getting this when I run the alias

```
cd:cd:13: no such file or directory: /Users/yoniPacheko/Documents/hej
```

it seems like syntax is wrong right?

Comment: It seems that there is no such file or directory !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok guys I did it!

WEll it depends where u want to point to.

The right answer to this question is:

```
alias fer='~/hej'
```

Apparently the zsh adds the rest.

Now if u want to point to a directory more far away, inside the USER-account it'll work pasting the whole link, for instance:

```
alias fer='~/Documents/tutorials/ruby/RnR/third_course_0/projects'
```